# Bootstrap - Vertical Alignment in a DIV

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to vertically center a Bootstrap column.

The current state of my try:

**HTML**

```
<div class="out">
 <div class="inn">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 lft v-align" >
       LEFT
     </div>  
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 rght">
        <div style="height: 200px">
           RIGHT
        <div>    
     </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.out{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.inn{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color: blue;
}
.lft{
  background-color: green;
}
.rght{
  background-color: orange;
}
.v-align {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I did try before:

```
 .col-sm-middle {
    vertical-align: middle;
 }
  .row-sm-height {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

But this piece kills the responsive behavior of the columns.

I also did try:

```
.vert{
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);  
}
```

This one doesn't work at all on bootstrap columns.

[**JSFFIDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/surracom/jbme0qx2/2/)

Any help will very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's columns serve no purpose in what you're trying to do. Simply use your `table-cell` trick without using the grid system:

**HTML**

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="lft">
            LEFT
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div style="height: 200px" class="rght">
            RIGHT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.out {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
.lft {
    background-color: green;
}
.rght {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jbme0qx2/5/)

If you are going to want it to be mobile responsive you can have these table styles only apply over a certain width:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .out {
        display:table;
        width:100%;
    }
    .col {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jbme0qx2/6/)

Comment: Where is the responsive behavior? I don have any problem centering in common divs. I did set col-xs-6 only due to the small window display. It will be set to col-xs-12 col-md-6 in the final result.

Comment: See my update. The divs will vertically centre in a row in their parent on medium screens and stack one under the other on anything smaller

Comment: Looks pretty nice. You rock! Let me know if you have any link to articles about this subject. Anyway, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Sergio Glad to have helped.